# parse matrix into single string in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, parsing, matrix, integer

I have a matrix of integers that I want to parse into a single string. I tried mat2str, num2str etc, but it always puts whitespaces in between the matrix cells.

Let's say I have the matrix:

```
2 4 5 1
4 9 2 0
1 9 5 3
```

What I want as an result is this:

```
ans = '245149201953'
```

I'm sure it can't be that hard, and probably I am missing something pretty obvious, but I'm just kind of stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use`sprintf´. I think that it will parse the argument columnwise, but that can be solved fairly easy, for example with a loop or with transpose. MATLAB actually does most of its operations columnwise, so if you have a choice I would recommend to take that into account.

ex)

```
a=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];
sprintf('%.0f',a) % %.0f for float, displayed with no decimals, use %d for int
```

Comment: thanks a lot everyone!
i used the sprintf method in the end, because it seemed to be the easiest one, but thanks to everyone else aswell :)

Answer (score 1):

Let your matrix be denoted as `M`. Some possible approaches are:

1. Use [`num2str`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) with a format specifier to avoid spaces:

   ```
   result = num2str(reshape(M.',1,[]), '%i');
   ```

   Change the format specifier `'%i'` to something else if needed.
2. Use [`mat2str`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html) and remove unwanted characters with [`regexprep`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html):

   ```
   result = regexprep(mat2str(M),'(\[|\]|\;|\s)','')
   ```
3. If your matrix contains only single digits: convert each number into its ASCII code and then cast to `char`:

   ```
   result = char(reshape(M.',1,[])+'0');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it mathematically:

```
ans=sum(((ones(1,numel(A))*10).^(numel(A):0)).*reshape(A',[],1)')
```